# NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml Django with StaticViewSitemap from app.urls

Tags: python, django

I would like to show urls in my sitemap.xml file from my website.urls file

From this url file I have no trouble to show *terms* *privacy* and other

**url**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import *  # NOQA
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from .sitemaps import StaticViewSitemap
from . import views


sitemaps = {
    'static': StaticViewSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('website.urls')),
    url(r'^terms/$', views.terms, name='terms'),
    url(r'^privacy/$', views.privacy, name='privacy'),
    url(r'^cdg/$', views.cdg, name='cdg'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^icon/$', views.icon, name='icon'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap')
]


# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  # NOQA
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        ) + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + urlpatterns  # NOQA
```

But when I want to get views from another url file (it's a app's url file locate inside a subfolder ) i have got an error.

here is my **sitemap.py** file

```
from django.contrib import sitemaps
from django.core.urlresolvers  import reverse

class StaticViewSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    priority= 0.5
    changefreq ='daily'

    def items(self):
        return ['terms','privacy', 'about', 'cdg','support']

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```

here is **website.url** py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

app_name = 'website'
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^support/$', views.support, name='support'),
    url(r'^galerie/$', views.galerie, name='galerie'),  
    url(r'^showcase/$', views.showcase, name='showcase'),
    url(r'^blog/$', views.blog, name='blog'),
    )
```

I have got this error :

```
NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml
Reverse for 'support' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/sitemap.xml
Django Version: 1.9.9
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'support' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: /Users/R/Virtualenvs/p3-dj1_9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 508
```

any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `support` URL is defined in an app which was included in your URLs file in this line:

```
url(r'^', include('website.urls')),
```

`reverse('support')` makes Django look for a URL named `'support'` in your main URLs file. To access this URL correctly, you need to use the correct [URL namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces), which defaults to your app's name.

In other words, this is the correct way to access the URL:

```
return reverse('website:support')
```

Which means that your `location` view must receive `'website:support'` instead of only `'support'`.

If you want the namespace to be other than `'website'`, simply pass the value you want to the `include()` method.

```
url(r'^', include('website.urls', namespace='another-name')),
```

Then, the `reverse` argument would be:

```
return reverse('another-name:support')
```

Comment: I can confirm that it also solves the same problem with Django==3.2